# How to test overall behaviour of a class in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, tdd, phpunit, integration-testing

I have a class which constructs the SQL and passes to Doctrine and it returns the result-set.

Now, I want to test the overall behavior of that class (basically without sending the request back to the Doctrine again and again).

I just want to test if this class is behaving properly.
Has anyone done similar testing? If yes please provide me suggestion link.

Comment: This is quite a standard use-case for test-doubles. You find use-cases already in the Phpunit manual: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on mocking.

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

This will allow you to simulate a database call (without actually connecting to a DB) and verify that "When my object gives doctrine X, it receives Y in return."

Comment: Note that there are other mocking frameworks that work well with PHPUnit (after reading the documentation), like "Mockery" or "Phake". They all do the same, but have different ways of being configured, and possibly one or the other might have an easier way creating mocks for the tests than the rest.

Comment: @Sven is correct, Phake (What I use personally) is a great alternative to the built in PHPUnit mocking solution.

Comment: Thank you mates. Let me go through the document link provided and will update you guyz.